# How to easily merge a table to unique elements of itself?

Tags: r, merge

I have this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(group=rep(1:3,each=3),
                 question=c("1.1.1. question 1","1.1.1.1. question1 with conditional","2.2.2.2. question2 with condtional", "2.2.2. question2","1.1.1.10. question 1 with conditional","3.3.3. question 3","3.3.3.2. question 3 with conditional","2.2.2.1. question 2 with conditional","3.3.3. Descirbe section 2.8"),
                 answer=c("yes","no","text","no","text","hello","yes","text","yes"),
                 parent_question=c("1.1.1. question 1","1.1.1. question 1","2.2.2. question2","2.2.2. question2","1.1.1. question 1","3.3.3. question 3","3.3.3. question 3","2.2.2. question2","3.3.3. Descirbe section 2.8"),
                 answer_parent=c("yes","yes","","","","","yes","","yes"))
```

What I want to do is create two new columns, called parent_question, and parent_answer.
So the parent_question to 1.1.1. is 1.1.1. and the parent question to 1.1.1.1. is 1.1.1. I know how do this by creating a parent_question dictionary and then merging it with this data set. And the parent_answer 1.1.1.1. is the answer to the parent_question 1.1.1. Is there an easy way to do this without creating a separate table for parent questions and parent answers and then merging them with the data?

Comment: Do you group `2.2.2.1` and `2.2.2.2` to `2.2.2`

Comment: Do you need `df %>% group_by(group, grp = str_extract(question, "^([0-9]+\\.){2}[0-9]+")) %>% arrange(group, question) %>% mutate(parent_question = first(question), parent_answer = first(answer))`

Comment: Yes, 2.2.2 would be the parent answer to 2.2.2.1 and 2.2.2.2

Comment: If you can update with the expected columns for that example, would be easier to crosscheck

Comment: Also some of the questions are like this question "4.4.4. Describe each things that are captured within 2.7 section"

Comment: For the answer part in your output, some of them are not filled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extract the pattern of numbers `1.1.1` or `1.1.1.1` from the start of the string with `str_extract`, create a logical 'flag', grouped by main question '1.1.1', '2.2.2', etc ('grp1'), create the 'p_q', 'p_a', by extracting the 'question/answer' where the 'flag' is TRUE.  If they are all FALSE, then return blank (`""`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
out <- df %>%
   mutate(grp1 = str_extract(question, "^([0-9]+\\.){2}[0-9]+"),
         grp2 = str_remove(str_extract(question, "^[0-9.]+"), "\\.$"), 
          flag = grp1 == grp2) %>%
   group_by(grp1) %>%
   mutate(parent_questionNew = question[which(flag)[1]]) %>%
   group_by(group, add = TRUE) %>%
   mutate(answer_parentNew = if(any(flag)) answer[which(flag & answer == "yes")[1]] 
         else replace(as.character(answer), answer != "yes", "")) %>%
   ungroup
out %>% 
 select(matches('parent'))
# A tibble: 9 x 4
#  parent_question             answer_parent parent_questionNew answer_parentNew
#  <fct>                       <fct>         <fct>              <chr>           
#1 1.1.1. question 1           "yes"         1.1.1. question 1  "yes"           
#2 1.1.1. question 1           "yes"         1.1.1. question 1  "yes"           
#3 2.2.2. question2            ""            2.2.2. question2   ""              
#4 2.2.2. question2            ""            2.2.2. question2    <NA>           
#5 1.1.1. question 1           ""            1.1.1. question 1  ""              
#6 3.3.3. question 3           ""            3.3.3. question 3   <NA>           
#7 3.3.3. question 3           "yes"         3.3.3. question 3  "yes"           
#8 2.2.2. question2            ""            2.2.2. question2   ""              
#9 3.3.3. Descirbe section 2.8 "yes"         3.3.3. question 3  "yes"
```

Comment: So I'm not sure how you produce the parent_question and parent_answer field. And why is p_q and p_a NA?

Comment: @Mel Are you using the updated code, because I find your updated dataset had `1.1.1.1.` dot at the end, which didn't match, so used `str_remove` in 'grp2'.  the 'p_q' and 'p_a' are the parent_question and parent_answer

Comment: @Mel I updated.  You can check the ouptut of `parent_questionNew` and `answer_parentNew`.  In your `parent_question`, the last entry seems to be different.  Is it a typo?

Comment: I'm still confused about what you are doing, can you please explain it a little further? I'm sorry

Comment: @Mel I am extracting the 1.1.1 and 1.1.1.1. substring in 'grp1', 'grp2', then create logical vector with 'flag'.  Once that 'flag' is created, I do a group by 'grp1' and extract the question and answer where 'flag' is TRUE

Comment: Where in the code is parent_question created though? there is no mutate(parent_question)?

Comment: @Mel `mutate(parent_questionNew = question[which(flag)[1]])`

Comment: Bu then that field is called parent_questionNew  and you have parent_question in the out table as well

Comment: @Mel It is your own column I just kept it as reference

Comment: Ooops, my bad. But parent_questionNew is giving me the same question throughout

Comment: @Mel Isn't that your expected output i.e `parent_question` and `answer_parent`. I was using that as reference to create those same column

Comment: @Mel May be you have loaded `plyr` as well which masked the `dplyr` mutate try with `dplyr::mutate(parent_questionNew = question[which(flag)[1]])`

Comment: Yes those are the reference columns, but running the code, I don't get the same parent_question and answer_parent

Comment: @Mel Are you saying that you are not getting the output I showed for `parent_questionNew`.  It could be an issue of function masking.  So, please specify `dplyr::` for each of the `mutate` as prefix to avoid `plyr::mutate` getting called

Comment: Also sorry about this but all my parent_answer's are yes in this case but what if they are not all yes?

Comment: @Mel If they are not 'yes', then it would be the first "yes" element or else you may need to change the logic about what you needed there

Comment: Hi @akrun, sorry to message back so late on this question, and thank you for all your help!  so this part of the code:                     
mutate(answer_parentNew = if(any(flag)) answer[which(flag & answer == "yes")[1]] 
else replace(as.character(answer), answer != "yes", "")),                          can it be just written as: mutate(answer_parentNew = ifelse(any(flag),answer[which(flag)[1]],NA))

Comment: @Mel the output of `if(any(` is a single TRUE/FALSE output.  So, you don't need `ifelse`